# arduino uno GSM/GPRS/GPS Shield (B) waveshare AT commands not working

Tags: arduino, gsm

I´m using a arduino uno with a gsm/gprs/gps shield (b) of waveshare

Using this link http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/GSM/GPRS/GPS_Shield_(B)

When I power up the shield power led on and net led is blinking.

But when i send AT commands not show nothing.

My code is:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial miserie(2,3); // RX, TX

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);  
    miserie.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
    if( Serial.available()>0 ){
        miserie.write(Serial.read());
    }
    if( miserie.available()>0 ){
        Serial.write(miserie.read());
    }
}
```

The shield is set like this image
http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/File:GSM-GPRS-GPS-Shield-B-UserManual-17.jpg

Do you have any idea why or what the exact problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was sending AT commands by the serial monitor.

When I send it by code like " miserie.print("AT") " then serial monitor show the answer.

so, I will continue trying.